# Why does Toshiba C50-C stay hot while suspended

Tags: nvidia, suspend, power-management, overheating

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit along side Windows 10 on a Toshiba C50-C.
Intel I7 gen 6, 8GB RAM, Nvidia Geforce 930M, Intel Dual Band Wifi 3165

Everything works perfectly except Suspend. The problem is that the laptop remains very hot while suspended and battery life while suspended is only around 3 to 4 hours.
[Laptop Specification](http://www.mytoshiba.com.au/products/computers/satellite/c50/pscpna-01601m/specifications) It wakes from suspend without problems.

The problem can easily be repeated by booting the laptop (Try Ubuntu) from 14.04, 15.10 and 16.04 media. The laptop stays hot while suspended either by closing the lid or by selecting Suspend in the drop-down menu.

I have collected and saved dmesg output covering the periods from boot to suspend and from suspend to collecting messages. I am unsure how to attach these logs.

Comment: I downloaded 16.04.1 this morning and burned a USB live disk.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a driver problem. Have you tried to install NVidia proprietary driver? Have you tried to install power management app like [TLP](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html)?

Comment: Thanks but given that the same problem occurs with or without Nvidia 361.42 activated I don't think the video card is the cause. TLP doesn't sound like it addresses the issue.

Comment: Just ran another test. Sudo pm-hibernate. Does all the right things except it stays hot.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded 16.04.1 this morning and burned a USB live disk.
I booted from that and suspended. It remained warm and consumed 30% of battery in 4 hours.
Worse than that, a shutdown doesn't stop battery use and heat dissipation. I have to either restart to Windows 10 then shut down or forcibly shut down using long hold on the power button.

It seems Mr Larabel is right https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Skylake-Concerns-MJG

Linux on Skylake (at least i7) is not viable. Very disappointing for a long time Ubuntu user.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed by installing Kernel 4.8 RC1[Kernel Bugzilla error report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=150321)